# Unable to download updateds?

Tags: 18.04

After ubuntu 18.04 is installed on my computer, I've got following message:

> Unable to download updates from
>   "extensions.gnome.org":[/*/*/*source/shell-extensions/*] failed to
>   download https://extensions.gnome.org//static/extensions.json: Cannot
>   resolve hostname

What does the message mean?

Comment: Could you add the error message as text and not just an image, please [edit] the question with that.

Comment: what is the output of `host extensions.gnome.org`

Comment: Are you behind company proxy etc.? What is your DNS Server ? Can you `ping extensions.gnome.org` ? Can you `ping 209.132.180.180` (=IP address of extensions.gnome.org).